# Protractor E2E Testing Error : Object [object Object] has no method 'getWindowHandle'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor

I am trying to check the pop up for facebook login opening on click of button .

```
Error : Object [object Object] has no method 'getWindowHandle'.
```

Code Snippet generating error :

```
describe('Tests', function() {
  var ptor;
  var handlePromise;
  var util = require('util');

  beforeEach(function() {
    ptor = protractor.getInstance();
    handlePromise = ptor.getAllWindowHandles();
    var handlesDone = false;
    ptor.get('/SiteB_Upgrade_Device/app/index.html#/Recommendations#page');
    ptor.findElement(by.id('fb')).click();
    ptor.ignoreSynchronization = true;
  });

  describe('login', function() {
    return it('should switch to popUp\'s handle', function() {
      handlePromise.then(function(handles) {
        var popUpHandle = handles[0];
        var handle = browser.driver.switchTo().window(popUpHandle).getWindowHandle();
        expect(handle).toEqual(popUpHandle);
      });
    },30000);
  });
});
```

Comment: have you tried 
`browser.driver.switchTo().window(popUpHandle).getWindowHandle().then(function (handle) { expect(handle).toEqual(popupHandle) });` ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply,but i have tried that but it doesn't work.

Comment: What you might try if it is possible in your test case is checking for  the url rather than the handle, something like `expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual('my/expected/url')` could do the trick if you run into troubles with `getWindowHandle()`

Comment: getCurrentUrl() matches the url of parent window but we need to test url of pop up window .

Comment: Don't have much time today to investigate but I noticed your use handles[0] which refer to the original window, the popup should be in handles[1].

Answer (score 6):

Here is what I currently use to navigate through popups/tabs :

```
// do stuff that will trigger the popup
// ...
browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {
  // switch to the popup
  browser.switchTo().window(handles[1]);
  // make sure the popup is now focused
  expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual('popup/url');
  // do stuff with the popup
  // ...
  // go back to the main window
  browser.switchTo().window(handles[0]);
  // make sure we are back to the main window
  expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual('original/url');
});
```

You just need to make sure that your popup is really a new window and not juste some kind of popover ( in which case you can just target it with css selectors ).

Another thing to keep in mind when you change tabs/popups it that the target page might not have angularjs loaded in it, which will render protractor useles. If you face this case you can simply use `browser.driver` as a replacement for `browser` to navigate a non angular page.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have tried browser.driver also but getting
error : Object [object Object] has no method 'getWindowHandle'
Code Snippet :
it('User should be able to login with correct Login credentials', function() {



var ptor = protractor.getInstance();
ptor.sleep(9999);
ptor.findElement(by.id('fb')).click().then(function() {
handlePromise.then(function(handles) {
var popUpHandle = handles[1];


browser.driver.switchTo().window(popUpHandle).getWindowHandle().then(
function (handle) { expect(handle).toEqual(popupHandle) });
});
},30000);

Comment: http://elementalselenium.com/tips/4-work-with-multiple-windows suggests we should not assume 0 is the main and 1 is the popup?